# Robot Framework, Selenium2Library two field with same id

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am on a page and it has email field with id="Email" and on that page it has a link. When I click that link then pop up window appears and it too have Email field with id="email".

I want to assert the placeholder of first email field but it is asserting the placeholder of send email field. Placeholder value is different in both email field.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: The image is missing.

Comment: The title name is same for both. Select Window is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword `Select Window` to choose a particular window for context of subsequent keywords.

Answer (score 0):

use `switchTo().window()` to switch to different windows and work with it.